# PHP not writing data in MYSQL

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is a school project and this particular page is to register a new user it does not display errors but  it does not fill the MYSQL data base the connection for the database is in another page and I used the require function functions.php is where I am writing the connection function please help :(

```
<?php
include_once("menu.php");
?>
 <form action="login.php" method="POST">
 <?php

                if ((isset($_POST['username']))&& (isset($_POST['password'])) && (isset($_POST['password2'])) && (isset($_POST['email'])))
                {
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];

                    if ($password == $password2)
                    {
                        require_once("functions.php");
                        $connection = connectToMySQL();
                        $Query = "SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$username'";
                        $Result = mysqli_query($connection,$Query)
                            or die("Error in the query :". mysqli_error($connection));

                        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($Result);
                            $counter = $row[0];

                        if ($counter > 0)
                        {
                            echo "Username alredy exsist with the movie assosiation website<br/>";
                            echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Back\"/>";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO 'tbl_users'(username,password,email,role) VALUES ('$username',sha1('$password'),'$email','registered')";

                            $insertResult = mysqli_query($connection,$insertQuery)
                                or die("Error in the query :". mysqli_error($connection));

                            echo "account created !! <br />";
                            echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" value=\"Log In\" onclick=\"location.href='login.php'\"> ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
            ?>
                    <label>
                        <span>Username:</span>
                        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your Username" required />
                    </label></br>
                    <label>
                        <span>Password</span>
                        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your Password" required />
                    </label></br>
                    <label>
                        <span>Re-Enter Password</span>
                        <input id="password2" type="password" name="password2"  placeholder="re-enter your Password" required />
                    </label></br>
                    <label>
                        <span>Email</span>
                        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email" required />
                    </label></br>
                    <label>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
                        <input  id="submit"  class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </label>
        </form>
    <?php
                } 
    ?>
<?php 
require_once("footer.php")
 ?>
```

Comment: `'tbl_users'` takeout single quote.

Comment: Good to see a school project using the MySQLi rather than the MySQL extension; but do schools teach the use of prepared statements/bind variables?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet Mr.Baker I'm still in the early stages :)

Comment: Better to learn the right way to do things from the outset, rather than learn the wrong way, and then have to relearn it again the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove single quote from your table name

try this

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `tbl_users`(username,password,email,role) VALUES ('$username',sha1('$password'),'$email','registered')";
```

instead of

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO 'tbl_users'(username,password,email,role) VALUES ('$username',sha1('$password'),'$email','registered')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in your sql statement.

Try this.

```
  $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (username,password,email,role) VALUES ('{$username}',sha1('{$password}'),'{$email}','registered')";
```

or this

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (username,password,email,role) VALUES ('".$username."',sha1('".$password."'),'".$email."','registered')";
```